# On the dimension of coordinate ring of an affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know that the coordinate ring of an affine variety is a valid K algebra(where K is an algebraically closed field on which we are working).So It is a ring and a K vector space at the same time.Now the following natural questions that come into ones mind is the following

1)Is the dimension of the coordinate ring  same as ring(i.e krull dimension)and K vector space?(I realize that the same question can be asked for any K algebra,and I spent some time to prove that they are equal in the case of coordinate ring but failed to see any relation between chain of prime ideals and basis of K vector space)

2)If the answer of the above is in negative then what could be a reasonable counterexample

3)Can we always give an explicit description of K basis of the coordinate ring of an affine variety as a K vector space?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: May I suggest looking at one of the simplest $K$-algebras, namely the polynomial ring $K[t]$, in one variable $t$? It has Krull dimension one, but infinite dimensional as a $K$-vector space. Question 3 has at least some relevant ideas in what is known as Grobner basis.

Comment: Thank you @Mohan for giving such an easy counterexample.

Comment: For an elliptic curve $E : y^2= x^3+x$ over $K$, its dimension is $1$ because its function field is $K(E)= \text{Frac}(K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x)) = K(x)[y]/(y^2-x^3-x)$ a finite extension of $K(x)$. A $K$-vector space basis for $K[x]$ is $\{x^n\}_{n \ge 0}$ thus a basis for $K[E] = K[x][y]/(y^2-x^3-x)$ is $\{x^n,x^n y\}_{n \ge 0}$. As a $K$-algebra it is generated by $x,y$.